# How to start/stop movie from macro?

Tags: libreoffice-calc

### How to start/stop movie from macro?

I want to be able to have an existing linked video control in my spreadsheet (ubuntu) and be able to control it with a macro (e.g. first goal is to support start and stop ).

https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/73907/how-to-startstop-movie-from-macro/

Answer (score 0):

The example in my answer here should work for Calc as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34534825/5100564.

Be sure to uncomment `com.sun.star.media.Manager_GStreamer` for Linux.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without calling createPlayer? Reason is: I'm trying to start an already existing video in my spreadsheet (I can use the Media Playback toolbar to manually control the video).