# How can i get user defined properties of an Open Office document

Tags: java, arrays, metadata, openoffice.org, openoffice-writer

I am trying to get the UserdefinedProperties of an Open Office Writer Document.

My questions are first how can i adress the currently open file in the writer?
And how can i access the metadata after I told the programmm from which file it should get the data?

hopefully someone of you can help me.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Check this interface [XDocumentProperties](https://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/document/XDocumentProperties.html#getUserDefinedProperties)

```
Reference< XDocumentInfoSupplier > xDocumentInfoSupplier(xComponent, UNO_QUERY);
Reference< XDocumentInfo > xDocumentInfo = xDocumentInfoSupplier->getDocumentInfo();

Reference< XDocumentPropertiesSupplier > xDocumentPropertiesSupplier(xDocumentInfo, UNO_QUERY);
Reference< XDocumentProperties > xDocumentProperties = xDocumentPropertiesSupplier->getDocumentProperties();

Reference< XPropertyContainer > xPropertyContainer = xDocumentProperties->getUserDefinedProperties();
Reference< XPropertySet > xPropertySet(xPropertyContainer, UNO_QUERY);

Reference< XPropertySetInfo > xPropertySetInfo = xPropertySet->getPropertySetInfo();
```

Sample code 
1. https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/ProUNO/Properties#Example:_query_and_change_the_properties
2. https://incubator.apache.org/odftoolkit/simple/document/cookbook/Manipulate%20Metadata.html#Access%20the%20user%20defined%20element

Comment: Already checeked it out but i dont know how to use it... sorry i am very new to programming

Comment: This step by step tutorial should help http://openofficejava.blogspot.co.uk/2009/05/openofficeorg-api.html

Answer (score 0):

Here are links to Java code to do these things:

> My questions are first how can i adress the currently open file in the
>   writer?

See [How to get the opened document using UNO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32718830/how-to-get-the-opened-document-using-uno)

> And how can i access the metadata after I told the programmm from
>   which file it should get the data?

See https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=80124.