# Accessing a Property of an odt File?

Tags: java, properties, metadata, document, openoffice.org

I asked lately how i can access the meta data of a odt file and the most recomended way to do this was using the apache tika library.

I tried finding out how i can use this Libraries in Detail.
Reading through all this stuff I find that this tika service is pretty hard (at least for someone that is new to Programming like me)

So my question is if maybe someone has a link to a side where there is like a step by step tutorial on how to use it or maybe as a different method to do this. I realy dont want you to do my work but i am working so long on this now and did not get this far so i think its time to ask for help here. :(

I want to acces and set only one property of my file which is the "DocumentID".

Thank you for helping and sorry for my maybe bad english but it is not my foreign language.

Comment: Did you try the methods and tutorials in the answers to your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34942951/how-can-i-get-user-defined-properties-of-an-open-office-document)?  I understand that the tutorials are difficult, but this is not a simple task for someone who is new to programming.

Comment: Yes i tried them out... I dont know if i did anything wrong or so but it did not seem to work. I know that this is not a simple task.

Comment: If you ask a specific question about one of the tutorials then it will be easier to answer.  For example, "Here is the code I tried, and here is the error message it produced."  Or, "It ran successfully, but the result was always a DocumentID of 0."  See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.